# how to intercept @modelattribute binding

Tags: spring, forms, binding, tags, modelattribute

Everyone.

I am using spring mvc framework, and spring form tag. I found unexpected thing when using form dynamically. For example,

```
public class Person {
    public List<Car> myCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    // getter and setter
}
```

below code is html form

```
<form:form modelAttribute="car" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="myCars[0].id">
<input type="text" name="myCars[0].name">
<input type="hidden" name="myCars[1].id">
<input type="text" name="myCars[1].name">
<input type="hidden" name="myCars[2].id">
<input type="text" name="myCars[2].name">
</form:form>
```

and next code is a spring form controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttribute({"car"})
public class CarController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(".....")
    public String form(@ModelAttribute Car car, BindingResult result, ...) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            ....
            return viewName;
        }
        ....
        return "redirect:/" + someWhere;
    }
}
```

1) I entered data into html form.
2) I can confirm that there are 3 Car objects in car.getMyCars()
3) There are some errors as binding, so it's redirected to viewName
4) I changed html form using jQuery like this

```
<form:form modelAttribute="car" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="myCars[0].id">
<input type="text" name="myCars[0].name">
<input type="hidden" name="myCars[1].id">
<input type="text" name="myCars[1].name">
</form:form>
```

and, submit. The result of this test is that @ModelAttribue Car car still remains 3rd element in List myCars. I expected to remain 2 Car elements, but it wasn't. I think it remained in session. And it was overwritten new form data to @ModelAttribute Car car object, but last 3rd element wasn't. My test shows that if form elements increase dynamically, binding object using @ModelAttribute have them. But though decreased dynamically, binding object still have them. I hope that Car car object have accurate number of form inputs. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't store it in the session then it will be recreated else only that will be bound that is available and not removed. Would be unexpected if you stored an object in the session submit only a single parameter and all the other parameters would suddenly be nulled...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks your response. I know if I use @SessionAttributes, not only they will be saved in session automatically by spring. but we can use spring form tag (`<form:errors/>`), Also I need to display data I entered when fails in controller. Can I do that, though they don't be saved in session with @SessionAttribute?

Comment: You don't need to save the object with `@SessionAttributes` for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes. it's working. If there are some errors, I sent model object to view like this `model.addAttribute("car", car)` as u said. I appreciate

Comment: You don't need to add it to the model it is already in the model.